# Using classification of previous sample in neural networks

Tags: classification, keras, time-series, cnn

I am trying to classify the state of a machine using different features coming from a set of sensors.

I am treating the problem like a time series, so I windowed the stream of the sensors each *X* seconds so that every sample has size ( *X* * *s_f* ).

I am obtaining fairly good results using a CNN but I would like to increase performances using some kind of approach that understands the patterns between different states.

For example if going from state A to B is more frequent than A->C I want the algorithm to include this in the classification.

My idea is to classify each sample taking into account the classification of the previous sample. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The approach you describe is predicting base on the features of the current step and the previous states.
If you believe that there is information on the previous states, than i would try to approach this problem in the **Time Series** approach.

The algorithms in this approach basically do what you request for, they predict based on the features of the current step and based on the previous states.
You can learn about the approach to understand it better in [this](https://youtu.be/6niqTuYFZLQ?t=770) cs231n video.

You can also look for tutorials on implementing models that fit the time-series problem.
The most popular model i know is caleld *LSTM*.
[Here](https://medium.com/@dclengacher/keras-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-c1f5febde03d) is a tutorial on implementing LSTM in keras.

I hope you will find it these helpful.
If you have any more questions or you would like more guidance, just let me know :)

Comment: I don't think you got my request because in my case, in the Test Set, the state is what I am searching for and each sample has a state.

Comment: But with unseen data this doesn't work! Imagine the test is 20 seconds of measurement from the sensors. I window it at 5 seconds, so I have 4 sample and I want to classify the state the machine was in for every sample. I don't have the state the machine was in so I miss the feature state! My idea is more to classify the first sample, than classify the second with an additional feature, which is the state predicted at the previous sample.

Comment: I've deleted my previous comment because i realized it doens't match your request yet. I'm writing a new comment not :)

Comment: My original idea was this: Say there is some probability dependency between the current state and the next state. If the features vector indicates on the current state, than there must be some probability dependency between the feature vectors as well. Therefore i would assume that a well trained lstm would require only the feature vectors, and it would take into consideration the current state and the dependency probability when predicting the next state.  But i understand you would still prefer to *explicitly* insert the previous state as a feature. and you might be right, it might help.

Comment: ok this is a good point. The problem is I don't know if this apply to my case. Imagine having a testset like I described, how would you define this relationship between different samples?

Comment: I'm not sure what is the issue to predict over the test set you described above. Could you elaborate more on the issue you see? In addition i would not define the probability relationship between the states explicitly. I would expect that the lstm would learn the relationship on its own. For example if in the training set, after the state s1 the state that will follow will always be s2, i would expect the lstm to be able to learn that. I would expect that when it will receive the features of s1, the next state it will predict will be always be s2.

Comment: Would you like to move this to a chat room and continue discussing there? :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86181/discussion-between-francesco-pegoraro-and-gal-avineri).